# WebSocket configuration in the Play Framework

Tags: java, websocket, playframework-2.6

I followed the [WebSocket in Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaWebSockets) and I implemented the application that worked with the WebSocket. I tested the application with [Simple WebSocket Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-websocket-client/pfdhoblngboilpfeibdedpjgfnlcodoo?hl=en). If the WebSocket connection is idle for 1 minute, the connection will be close. I want to increase the idle connection to 10 minutes or more. I can't find any configuration for the WebSocket in Play Documentation. Can you help me to figure out?